# setting background image of UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

So I have the following code to set the segmented control background color:

```
UISegmentedControl * segmentedCtrl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 35)];
[segmentedCtrl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedCtrl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-home.png"] atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-star.png"] atIndex:1 animated:NO];
```

It all works fine except that when I click on the segment I can see the blue button highlighted. How do I disable this highlight? Here's a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UISegmentControl has a Divider between two segments. By using the following code you can change the divider background.

```
[segmentedCtrl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider_selected.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedCtrl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider_normal.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Where divider_selected.png is a image which you used for selected state. Where as divider_normal.png is a image which you used for normal state.

Hope this will help....

Comment: what would be the size of divider image ??

Comment: I had 5 × 56.  In this height may vary according to your segment control height.

Comment: I am doing that, but my segmentedCtrl's frame gets enlarged by 5 pixels! What am I doing wrong? Are there any *requirements* for the divider image (like transparency, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Set your same background images for the highlighted state:

```
[segmentedCtrl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```